# Adding multiple files with JFileChooser

Tags: java, jfilechooser

I'm looking to make an application that allows you to attach files from your computer. For example, when the JFileChooser opens you have the option to select multiple files and when you click "add" it adds it to the window and you can then have different for what you want to do with those files. Similar to attaching files in an email. All the code I have to show is the JFileChooser because I figure I should learn how to do this before I go any further.

Thanks in advance

```
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import java.io.File;

public class Locket {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    File f = new File("Desktop");
    chooser.setCurrentDirectory(f);

    chooser.showOpenDialog(null);

}
```

}

Answer (score 17, accepted):

JFileChooser API already provides a method named `getSelectedFiles()`. You can use it for multiple selection. It returns an array of file objects, i.e. `File[]`.

Answer (score 12):

You need to use [`JFileChooser#setMultiSelectionEnabled`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#setMultiSelectionEnabled%28boolean%29) and set it to true.  This will allow the user to be able to select multiple files

Comment: That part I got down. just trying to figure out how to get the files into the window.