# JFileChooser to select a multiple file java

Tags: java, swing

That is my code to the JFileChooser to select a file now i want to select multiple file what to do

```
JFileChooser chose=new JFileChooser();
chose.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
int r=chose.showOpenDialog(new JFrame());
if(r == chose.APPROVE_OPTION){
    String filepath= chose.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
}
```

how to select a multiple file using JFileChooser Please Help...

Comment: There are at least two duplicates of this question, please try Googleing before asking!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922152/jfilechooser-to-open-multiple-txt-files  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13060371/adding-multiple-files-with-jfilechooser

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`chose.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true)`

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
chooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
chooser.showOpenDialog(frame);
File[] files = chooser.getSelectedFiles();
```